# How to query a SQL statement which depends on other values of same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, postgresql, relational-database

I have a table with 3 columns( name, objectroot_dn, distinguishedname). Here **distinguishedname** is like a parent to **objectroot_dn**. I have to find whether for each **objectroot_dn** is there a child exists or not?

I can do this using the query below. It will return *True* if there is a child, *False* if there is not. But my problem is when the total dataset gets increased it takes lots of time.

For example, If the total number of row is 50,000 then it takes 10 mins for this query to complete.

Since I'm using a framework for different database, I can't index the columns.

```
SELECT
  name,
  objectroot_dn,
  distinguishedname,
  CASE
  WHEN (SELECT count(*)
        FROM (SELECT name
              FROM elaoucontainergeneraldetails
              WHERE objectroot_dn = dn.distinguishedname
              LIMIT 1) AS tabel1) > 0
    THEN 'True'
  ELSE 'False'
  END
FROM elaoucontainergeneraldetails AS dn
WHERE objectroot_dn = 'SOME_VALUE';
```

Please let me know how can I increase the speed of this query.

Thanks in advance. Appreciate all help.

Comment: You say you can't index columns, then you're in deep trouble... (How do you create tables?)

Comment: I would try to split the process into two (with the aid of a cursor). The first part will query and return the list of records that need to be updated (and possible to what (YES/NO); the second part will loop through the cursor and perform the updates. You should consider, however, that executing 50,000 updates is going to take some time whatever you do (though should not take 10 minutes)..

Comment: "Since I'm using a framework for different database, I can't index the columns" what prevents you from using the mysql console to create indexes?

Comment: @FDavidov Reimplementing a nested loop join in the application is bound to perform worse than doing it in the database.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe not necessarily. I have seen too many times already that such split does work and, in some cases, it outperforms other approaches.

Comment: That would be a bad database system indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the same solution using left join or exists:

```
SELECT
      dn.name,
      dn.objectroot_dn,
      dn.distinguishedname,
      CASE
      WHEN dn_in.objectroot_dn is not null
        THEN 'True'
      ELSE 'False'
      END
    FROM elaoucontainergeneraldetails AS dn
    LEFT JOIN elaoucontainergeneraldetails dn_in on dn_in.objectroot_dn = dn.distinguishedname
    WHERE objectroot_dn = 'SOME_VALUE';
```

Comment: If more than one row on the right side matches, you would end up with more than one result rows, all showing `'True'`.

Comment: Yeah, If i have at least one row to match the condition then its True

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS(subquery)` yields a boolean value:

```
SELECT dn.name
  , dn.objectroot_dn
  , dn.distinguishedname
  , EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM elaoucontainergeneraldetails nx
              WHERE nx.objectroot_dn = dn.distinguishedname
              )  AS truth_value
FROM elaoucontainergeneraldetails AS dn
WHERE dn.objectroot_dn = 'SOME_VALUE'
   ;
```